# Is the Non Terminal Symbol X nullable

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, nullable

I have been following [this](http://onlinevideolecture.com/?course_id=1278&lecture_no=23) video tutorial series on Compiler design. The current video is about calculating the first and follow function in predictive parse table. My question is for the following production rules

```
Z-->XYZ    Y--> c             X-->a
Z-->d      Y-->E(epsilon)     X-->bYe
```

Can we reduce `X` to `E` Empty string. Or in another way is `X` nullable. In my opinion when we use the rule `X-->bYe` `X` can be reduced to `Y` and therefore the non terminal symbol`X` is nullable since `Y-->E (epsilon)`. 
The tutor says that `X` is not nullable and hence I am confused. Will be grateful if someone can clear my confusion. The video series was posted 4 years ago and I get no reply from the video author.

Comment: I don't follow you. How can you reduce X to Y using the rule X-->bYe?

Comment: thanks @ThomasPadron-McCarthy. I thought X can be replaced by either of the 3 symols, i.e b Y or e.

Comment: Aha. No, X-->bYe means X can be replaced by the sequence bYe, or rather b(something that Y can be replaced by)e. Othwerise it might be written as X-->b|Y|e.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasPadron-McCarthy now I am clear on this one.

Comment: Plus, when I use the term "reduce", I use it the other way around. So, for example, given the production X-->abc I would say that you can reduce abc to X, but not X to abc. I'm not sure if this usage is universal.

Comment: Ok, I'll check on  reduce. Your way seems correct to me as well.